# Подскажите, как понимать предложение?

Tags: смысл, деловой-язык

Ежемесячная выплата в связи с рождением (усыновлением) первого ребенка осуществляется женщине, родившей (усыновившей) первого ребенка, или отцу (усыновителю) либо опекуну ребенка в случае смерти женщины, отца (усыновителя), объявления их умершими, лишения их родительских прав или в случае отмены усыновления ребенка.

Отец имеет право получить выплату наравне с матерью или же только в случае смерти матери?
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как понимать предложение?

Answer (score 2):

Предложение, как мне кажется, составлено некорректно (со всех точек зрения — и юридической, и попросту смысловой). Однозначный вывод из этого "информативного набора" сделать невозможно.

Если родители (усыновители) имеют одинаковые права на получение пособия, то обычно пишут так: пособие выплачивается одному из родителей (усыновителей).

Вот [**выдержка**](http://www.dszn.ru/activities/sotsialnye_vyplaty_i_posobiya/vyplaty_semyam_s_detmi/ezhemesyachnaya-vyplata-v-svyazi-s-rozhdeniem-usynovleniem-pervogo-rebenka/) из Федерального закона.
Кто имеет право:
1) **женщина**, родившая (усыновившая) первого ребенка;
2) отец (усыновитель) в случае смерти женщины, родившей (усыновившей) ребенка, объявления ее умершей, лишения ее родительских прав или в случае отмены усыновления;
3) опекун ребенка, в случае смерти родителей (усыновителей), объявления их умершими, лишения их родительских прав или в случае отмены усыновления.

В некоторых источниках есть дополнения:
также возможно обращение опекуна в связи с рождением ребенка у несовершеннолетнего родителя, не достигшего возраста 16 лет (в третьем пункте);
4) Опекун ребенка, мать которого признана судом недееспособной.

Делаем вывод: в первую очередь получатель — женщина.

Answer (score 0):

Ежемесячная выплата в связи с рождением (усыновлением) первого ребенка осуществляется **(1)** женщине, родившей (усыновившей) первого ребенка, или отцу (усыновителю)

либо **(2)** опекуну ребенка в случае смерти женщины, отца (усыновителя), объявления их умершими, лишения их родительских прав или в случае отмены усыновления ребенка.

**Я думаю, что выплату может получать или мать, или отец (у них равные права).**

В случае же их смерти, лишения родительских прав или отмены усыновления выплату будет получать **опекун.**

Comment: Вопрос был такой: как понимать данное предложение? Ответ должен быть такой: данное предложение понимается следующим образом, что следует из  грамматики этого предложения. Это же форум русского языка, а не юридическая консультация по вопросам федерального законодательства..

Comment: Большая просьба к участнику, поставившего за ответ знак минус. Объясните, как Вы понимаете грамматику этого предложения, в чем  здесь ошибка? Как вы думаете, почему использованы разные разделительные союзы (ИЛИ, ЛИБО), какой в этом смысл?

Comment: Спасибо большое!Просто у меня вид на жительство в РФ,а у отца и ребенка гражданство РФ.Вначале были выплаты на первенца,а теперь требуют их вернуть,так как якобы нам их ошибочно назначили.Вот и не знаем,как быть...